# Directive displaying Error: [$parse:lexerr] after moving template to templateURL

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I have a directive working without any issues when the HTML markup is written in the template section of the directive.

I've just moved the HTML markup in a .html file and on load of the page, i am seeing:

```
Error: [$parse:lexerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$parse/lexerr?p0=Unexpected%20next%20character%20&p1=s%2016-16%20%5B%5C%5D&p2=option.name%20%3D%3D%3D%20%5C'choices%5C'
```

Original directive:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            template: '<p>' +
            '<div ng-repeat="select in data.output">' +
            '<div ng-if= "select.name === \'choices\'">' +
            '<p ng-repeat="choice in select.value"><label><input type="radio" ng-model="data.input[0].value" ng-value="$index" >{{choice}}</label></p>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</p>'
        }
    }
);
```

New:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
    return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                data: "="
            },
            templateUrl: 'home/mydirective.html'
        }
    }
);
```

I page load i can see the http request for mydirective.html and the markup is correct, however the lexerr then appears in the console.

Comment: Put your html also 'mydirective.html'. Might be a problem with that.

Comment: Better if you can create a fiddle

Comment: you html markup should be `'<p><div ng-repeat="select in data.output"><div ng-if= "select.name === \'choices\'"><p ng-repeat="choice in select.value"><label><input type="radio" ng-model="data.input[0].value" ng-value="$index" >{{choice}}</label></p></div></div></p>` without string concatenation

Comment: @OamPsy I've added answer..look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html should not contain concatenation that will mess while angular `$compile` that template. It should be plain html.

**mydirective.html**

```
<p>
    <div ng-repeat="select in data.output">
        <div ng-if="select.name === 'choices'">
            <p ng-repeat="choice in select.value">
                <label>
                    <input type="radio" ng-model="data.input[0].value" ng-value="$index">{{choice}}</label>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: thanks, in the 3rd line, your div should not contain the \ ;)

Comment: @OamPsy thank for head up..I edited my answer..do upvote & accept it..if it does worked for you..;)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was related to using single quote with a backslash (`\'`) in the `.html`-file. It was working well when the html was put directly inside the directive using `template`.
But it threw an error when it was put in a separate `.html`-file and using `templateUrl`. So changing `ng-class="{\'something\'}"` to `ng-class="{'something'}"` fixed it for me. Hope this will save someone else couple of hours.